# Need to get JSON arraySize in substitution Data

Tags: sparkpost

I need to get size of array in substitution data. I tried to use local var outside each loop but it did not work. Is there some in build method to get array size in substitution data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `#` to return array length.  Given this substitution data:

```
{
    "arr": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Use the following in your message template:

`{{#arr}}`